# AngularJS- some of my scope variables not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm a new developer using Angular JS to create an orders page for an app I created in Ruby on Rails.  I would like to get a few Angular variables to display:

- order.id *(displays)*
- order.user.email *(does not display)*
- order.total *(does not display)*
- order.product.name *(displays)*

Only 2 of the 4 variables display.  When I put a string or integer into the {{}} Angular notation in place of *order.total | currency*, the string or integer displays.  However, when I try the same with *order.product.name*, nothing happens.

Here is my relevant code:

View.html:

```
<div ng-controller="OrdersCtrl">
<h1>Orders</h1>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="addOrder()">
        <strong>Add Order: </strong>
        <select ng-model="newOrder.product_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Product</option>
            <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.id}}">    {{product.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" step="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" ng-model="newOrder.total">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="newOrder.product_id">
        <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
    </form>

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <td>Order ID</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td></td>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:'-id':reverse">
        <td>
            {{order.id}}<small ng-show="order.user_id"><br>-{{order.user.email}}</small>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>{{order.total | currency}}</strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{order.product.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="deleteOrder(order)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller (app.js)

```
var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngResource']);
//Workaround to get Angular running
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['shop'])
});
//factory for models
app.factory('models', ['$resource', function($resource){
var orders_model = $resource("/orders/:id.json", {id: "@id"});
var products_model = $resource("/products/:id.json", {id: "@id"});
var x = {
    orders: orders_model,
    products: products_model
};
return x;
}]);
//connect app to OrdersCtrl controller
app.controller('OrdersCtrl', ['$scope', 'models', function($scope, models){
// Here will be all code belonging to this controller
$scope.orders = models.orders.query();
$scope.products = models.products.query();
//add new orders
$scope.addOrder = function(){
    //only orders with product id or zero total gets added
    if(!$scope.newOrder.product_id || $scope.newOrder.total === ''){      return; }
    //Order can be submitted if product_id and total are filled out
    order = models.orders.save($scope.newOrder, function(){ //POST
        recent_order = models.orders.get({id: order.id});
        $scope.orders.push(recent_order);
        $scope.newOrder = '';
    });
}
//delete orders
$scope.deleteOrder = function(order){
    models.orders.delete(order);
    $scope.orders.splice($scope.orders.indexOf(order), 1);
};
}]);
```

Comment: Can you console.log the $scope.orders variable and show use the content?

Comment: Sure, I added the id "total" to html td tag: `<strong>{{order.total | currency}}</strong>`, and used console log to get this:                                  `ChildScope {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: ChildScope, $$watchers: Array[5], $$listeners: Object…}$$ChildScope: null$$childHead: null$$childTail: null$$listenerCount: Object$$listeners: Object$$nextSibling: ChildScope$$prevSibling: null$$transcluded: true$$watchers: Array[5]$$watchersCount: 5$even: true$first: true$id: 13$index: 0$last: false$middle: false$odd: false$parent: Scopeorder: Resource__proto__: Scope`

Comment: That's a lot of stuff. I just want to see the $scope.orders.

Comment: My mistake. Just starting out as a developer.  Put `console.log($scope.orders)` at my controller and reloaded the page.  This was my result: `[$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]
0:
Resource
$$hashKey
:
"object:12"
id
:
28
product
:
Object
product_id
:
"3"
user_id
:
null
__proto__
:
Object`     There were a total of seven `Resource`, each one making up one of my orders.  After 6: Resource was this `$promise: Promise  $resolved: true    length: 7  __proto:__:Array[0]`

Comment: Any chance you can create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: That'll be my next step. Just bought new Mac and am in the file transfer process tonight. Will try that when I my computers finish the transfer

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your patience.  Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JonSho/q9ygsesx/#&togetherjs=RkFOEihQTT